# Best practices for dependent fields in a django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, getter-setter

For database indexing purposes, the email field on a model needs to be stored in reverse.  I end up needing access to both the reversed and forward version of the email field.  I'm curious as to which of the following methods would be considered best practice.

**Method A**
Override the `save` method on the model.  This method denormalizes the database some and doesn't work with the `update` method on a queryset.  Some need to override forms generated for the model.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  email_forward = models.CharField(max_length = 320)
  email_reversed = models.CharField(max_length = 320)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.email_reversed = reversed(self.email_forward)
    super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Method B**
This way has better database normalization.  Still allows you to use the `update` method on querysets.  Screws up forms so that you end up having to override all of the default forms generated for the model.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  _email = models.CharField(max_length = 320)

  @property
  def email_forward(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'email_f'):
      self.email_f = reversed(self._email)
    return self.email_f

  @email.setter
  def email_forward(self, value):
    self.email_f = value
    self._email = reversed(value)

  @propery
  def email_reversed(self):
    return self._email
```

**Clarification**

Any alternative answers need to meet the minimum requirement of having the reversed email stored in the database.  This question is however, not so much about finding an answer to this specific problem, but getting feedback on best practices for this sort of scenario where you have two fields which can be computed from one another, but one is required in a frontend context, and the other in a backend context

Answer (score 1):

The Model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=320)

    def _get_email_reversed(self):
        return self.email[::-1]

    def _set_email_reversed(self, value):
        self.email = value[::-1]

    email_reversed=property(_get_email_reversed, _set_email_reversed)
```

And the Form:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

Not sure what you meant by "Screws up the form", but this model form will only have one field - the `email`. I have also added an example of how the models are used:

```
def test_foo(self):
    foo = Foo()
    foo.email = 'moc.elpmaxe@liametset'
    self.assertEquals(foo.email_reversed, 'testemail@example.com')

def test_set_foo_reversed(self):
    foo = Foo()
    foo.email_reversed = 'testemail@example.com'
    self.assertEquals(foo.email, 'moc.elpmaxe@liametset')
```

Comment: the email address has to be stored reversed in the database for indexing purposes.  That is kind of besides the point though.  Maybe a better wording would be, that I need the non-human readable version in the database, but there is a human readable version that I need access to as well, and in things like forms, I never need to see the non-human readable version.

Comment: Actually you can store the reversed version of the email in the code above (I've updated the test code for a simple example). Calling `foo.email_reversed` would then give you the proper forward version. If you are looking for something non-secure, but non-human readable, you can do simple things like base64 encode. If you are looking for something SECURE (i.e., the email cannot be simply decrypted by anyone), you will need to look into encryption.

Comment: It isn't a security issue and the value has to be stored in the database, in its reversed format.  Due to how my database uses indexes, A query `WHERE email LIKE foo%` does use the index, but the query `WHERE email LIKE %foo` will not.  That aside, this question isn't so much about the specific problem because either of my solutions work.  I'm curious as to what people feel the the proper best practice.